# Python scrapy not doing anything

Tags: python, scrapy

I've started learning `Python,` and I'm loving it so far. I keep looking at different libraries and what not. So I stumbled upon `Scrapy` and thought I would give it a try. I wanted to get all the links from `daylerees` colour schemes (from github) and dump them somewhere for a quick access.

So I did this:

```
import scrapy


class ThemeItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()


class ThemeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'themespider'
    start_urls = ['https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes/tree/master/jetbrains']

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//a[@class="js-directory-link"]'):
            url = ThemeItem()
            url['name'] = sel.xpath('text()')
            url['link'] = sel.xpath('@href')

            yield url
```

And it is not outputting anything at all. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

---

I'm running it like this:
`scrapy runspider spider.py`

Comment: Your script isn't outputting anything because it's not doing anything. You're importing a library and then defining two classes. No 'procedure', so to speak, is being executed, hence no output.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to mention - I'm doing `scrapy runspider spider.py` from the console.

Comment: @ChrisSprague I'm pretty sure the OP is running it via `scrapy` cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements containing the `js-directory-link` class have also other classes, example:

```
<a href="/daylerees/colour-schemes/tree/master/jetbrains/contrast" class="js-directory-link js-navigation-open" id="c8fd07f040a8f2dc85f5b2d3804ea3db-6b332f6820ec47d7ade641dbf72108b025b10440" title="contrast">contrast</a>
```

You need to use a partial class attribute match via `contains()`:

```
//a[contains(@class, "js-directory-link")]
```

Or, you may use [CSS selectors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.css):

```
for sel in response.css('a.js-directory-link'):
```

---

Though I would really think about using [github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) instead.

Comment: Ah it makes sense! I changed it to the CSS selector, and it is outputting this: `{'link': [<Selector xpath='@href' data=u'/daylerees/colour-schemes/tree/master/je'>], 'name': [<Selector xpath='text()' data=u'contrast'>]}`. I think I will use the github's API instead. Thanks!

Comment: @SuchMuchCode yeah, you've got selectors printed. Call `extract()` on them to have real values, e.g. `sel.xpath('text()').extract()`. Thanks.